# Is it possible to do motivational poster with paperclip gem alone?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, rubygems

Is it possible to do motivational poster in rails with paperclip gem alone or will I need some kind of image processor like RMAGICK?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paperclip [defers to ImageMagick](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#image-processor) to process images, so you’ll need it anyway.